# How come buffer overflow happens in whatsapp like app, if canary exists

Tags: buffer-overflow

I recently read that whatsapp has fallen again to buffer overflow attacks.
But I wonder, why canary protection isn't used. I guess that for some reason, Facebook, and other code companies don't use it globally for a reason or it doesn't protect some of the buffer overflow attacks, if so why or how?

Comment: A warrant canary is a completely different concept

Comment: Have you seen the wiki entry for this concept? It answers your questions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#A_canary_example

Comment: it actually doesn't. It doesn't say what makes companies not using it. It has said that it has some performance overhead. yet, security is far more important to them than some milliseconds spared.

Comment: That's an assumption on the impact of canaries on performance and security.... The point you missed is that the canary is discoverable and can be avoided.

Comment: If you won't accept the facts, then you want to understand the underlying decision-making process, which we cannot help with.

Comment: Typically, a canary is defeated with an infoleak.